# Animated Spinner Loader with image and mask

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I own an image as ci-below attached!

I would like to make a loader that loading be representing this animation (ci-below)!

I have a small idea of ​​the code that I use for this but hmmm, I'd like your opinion on the matter and if possible differente ideas on how to implement it!

[image: Image for my loader animation]

[image: Animation as wanted !]

**Quick concept code :**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^(void) {
        //rotate half way (use 179.9 for direction, -179.9 is left)
        self.refreshButton.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.refreshButton.transform,179.9*M_PI/180);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //still loading? rotate half again
        if ([self.superAwesomeWebView isLoading]) {
            [self animateLoadButton];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (requires ARC):

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dacircularprogress

Comment: I will study it! i'm waiting more responses before voting, thank you